# Firebase: how to intercept password changed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using `FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` for register and `FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` for login.

After doin that, `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is never null, only after doin a `FirebaseAuth.signOut()`.

So the questions is: how to intercept if account password has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Firebase Authentication doesn't fire any event when a user changes their password.

You can of course catch most changes by embedding the firing of an event into your own application code. But that can be circumvented by users willing to spend the effort.

So there currently is no reliable way to detect whenever a user changes their password. I'd recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), since those do often help the team determines priorities.

Comment: Thank you, so what could be a workaround? Could I catch that with Firebase Functions and notify all the devices with that user to signOut? Because actually, when I launch my app on a device already logged in, after changing password, I don't know how to handle it, the user would be stuck in a limbo without know why he's not receiving any data, but the cached ones.

Comment: There is no event fired for a password change, that includes to [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). I don't really understand the problem you're describing: can you show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.
Yesterday I didn't explain very well:
Let's think I got 2 devices, one is logged to Firebase with test@email.com, other is not logged yet, so I choose to reset/change my password. First device still working until the session expires, then I get:
`(0.6.6-dev) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ TOKEN_EXPIRED ]. `
and the app just can read from cached data. I would like to handle that at the root, when I start my app, withou handling the exception in another weird way :)